# C Windows - Get IPv4 bandwidth usage Statistics

Tags: c, windows, winapi, networking

With the .NET Framework we can retrieve the received and sent bytes with the following functions.

```
NetworkInterface.GetIPv4Statistics().BytesReceived
NetworkInterface.GetIPv4Statistics().BytesSent
```

But i cannot find the alternative in native C. The closest i found was the `GetIpStatistics`. However this seems to be global instead of per interface.

Can anyone point me into the right direction?

Comment: None of what you have there has anything to do with bandwidth, which is the maximum number of bits per second a link can send. For example, if your interface is 1000BASE-T, the bandwidth is 1 Gbps. I think you mean data used, which is very different than bandwidth.

Comment: In general. When talking about the current bandwidth usage. The specified .net functions describes exactly what's needed.

Comment: I don't think you understand what bandwidth is. For example, a 1000BASE-T ethernet connection will always send data at 1 Gbps because that is the bandwidth of the link. You are want how many bits are sent, and that is not bandwidth, that is data usage.

Comment: Every 'bandwidth monitoring'-tool uses this terminology exactly like i used in my post. Altough it is not theoretically correct, everyone knows exact what i mean.

Comment: That's really not true. I see people refer to the throughput (also, not bandwidth or data usage) as bandwidth, and they say that bandwidth monitoring tools measure that. If you use the correct terminology, there will be no confusion. You cannot use the single term to mean all three very different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allthough we can all furiously debate what the correct terminology is, I think you can find what you seek by calling the [GetIfTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365943.aspx) function.

This will return a [MIB_IFTABLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366842.aspx) struct, which in turn has [MIB_IFROW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366836.aspx) elements that contain the data you're looking for for the various network interfaces on your machine.